# Stuck on MIT's 6.005 Elements of Software Construction, cannot implement computePiInHex()

Tags: java, hex, pi

I am currently doing MIT's OCW 6.005 Elements of Software Construction for self- study.

I am on [problem set 1](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Felectrical-engineering-and-computer-science%2F6-005-elements-of-software-construction-fall-2011%2Fassignments%2FMIT6_005F11_ps1.pdf).

The part I am currently stuck on is 1.d. It asks me to "Implement computePiInHex() in PiGenerator. Note that this function should
only return the fractional digits of Pi, and not the leading 3."

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class PiGenerator {
/**
 * Returns precision hexadecimal digits of the fractional part of pi.
 * Returns digits in most significant to least significant order.
 * 
 * If precision < 0, return null.
 * 
 * @param precision The number of digits after the decimal place to
 *                  retrieve.
 * @return precision digits of pi in hexadecimal.
 */
public static int[] computePiInHex(int precision) {
    if(precision < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return new int[0];
}

/**
 * Computes a^b mod m
 * 
 * If a < 0, b < 0, or m < 0, return -1.
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @param m
 * @return a^b mod m
 */
public static int powerMod(int a, int b, int m) {
   if(a < 0 || b < 0 || m < 0)
       return -1;

   return (int) (Math.pow(a, b))  % m;
}

/**
 * Computes the nth digit of Pi in base-16.
 * 
 * If n < 0, return -1.
 * 
 * @param n The digit of Pi to retrieve in base-16.
 * @return The nth digit of Pi in base-16.
 */
public static int piDigit(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return -1;

    n -= 1;
    double x = 4 * piTerm(1, n) - 2 * piTerm(4, n) -
               piTerm(5, n) - piTerm(6, n);
    x = x - Math.floor(x);

    return (int)(x * 16);
}

private static double piTerm(int j, int n) {
    // Calculate the left sum
    double s = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; ++k) {
        int r = 8 * k + j;
        s += powerMod(16, n-k, r) / (double) r;
        s = s - Math.floor(s);
    }

    // Calculate the right sum
    double t = 0;
    int k = n+1;
    // Keep iterating until t converges (stops changing)
    while (true) {
        int r = 8 * k + j;
        double newt = t + Math.pow(16, n-k) / r;
        if (t == newt) {
            break;
        } else {
            t = newt;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    return s+t;
  }
}
```

The main method initiates a constant and then calls computePiInHex().

```
public static final int PI_PRECISION = 10000;

int [] piHexDigits  = PiGenerator.computePiInHex(PI_PRECISION);
```

From my knowledge, the method piDigits() gets the nth digit of pi in base 16. So in computePiHex, should implement the [BBP digit-extraction algorithm for Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80)? Otherwise could someone point me in the right direction because I don't know what they're asking for in computePiInHex().

Answer (score 0):

Try a different powermod algorithm.

For me this article helped a lot:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-005-elements-of-software-construction-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_005F11_ps1.pdf

The actual algorithm I used is based on the pseudocode from Applied Cryptography by Bruce Schneier
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    if modulus = 1 then return 0
    Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
    result := 1
    base := base mod modulus
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base := (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```